# Android. Need to always rebuild project to my layout XML changes are compiled. Run app is not enouph

Tags: android

I'm encountering an issue in my Android app where changes made to the XML layout are not taking effect and becoming visible in the app. This happens with `Run 'app'` so I always need to `Rebuild project` to make the changes "visible" on the app.

This of course takes loonger than expected. Code changes in a kotlin activity or viewmodel, with `Run 'app'` suffices to them become visible.

This problem persists across Android Studio versions Electric Eel and Jellyfish, and is happening in a larger project. Did a test and the issue doesn't occur in a smaller project, so it seems to be linked to the project's size.

Anyone has had the same issue and if so, managed to address it?